# Application Insights not working in locally running Azure Worker Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to get app insights to work in a local .NET 7 Worker Azure Function

```
public class Tools
{
    public Tools(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Tools>();
    }
    
    [Function("test-app-insights")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> TestAppInsightsAsync([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "tools/test-app-insights")]
            HttpRequest req)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("HELLOFROMNEWFUNCTION");
        await Task.Yield();

        var response = 0;
        var okResponse = new OkObjectResult(response);
        return okResponse;
    }
}
```

I have added the code below to configure services but nothing is shown in App Insights, and there are no errors

```
        var appInsightsConnectionString = "MY CONNECTION STRING";

        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService((a =>
        {
            a.EnableAdaptiveSampling = false;
            a.ConnectionString = appInsightsConnectionString;
        }));
```

Does anyone know what I have missed?

I have this in the logging section of my host.json

```
"logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "System": "Warning",
      "Host": "Error",
      "Function": "Error",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Information"
    },
    "Serilog": {
      "MinimumLevel": "Information",
      "WriteTo": [
        {
          "Name": "Console",
          "Args": {
            "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level} | {RequestId} - {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true
      }
    }
  },
```

Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create Application Insights Instance and copy the Instrumentation key for later use.

[image]

- Create a `Function App`.
  [image]
- Enable `Application Insights` option while creating the Function App.
- Select the Application Insights which we have created in the previous step.

[image]

- Make sure that the region of Application Insights and Function App are same.
- `InstrumentationKey` will be added in the `Application Settings` automatically once we enable the `ApplicationInsights`.

[image]

- In Visual Studio, Create a Function App with .NET 7 Isolated.

***My `host.json`:***

```cs
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***My `local.settings.json`:***

```cs
{

"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
"APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "Copy from Application Insights "
 }
}
```

***My Traces in `Azure Application Insights` Instance:***

[image]

Comment: @Paul - Glad it cleared the issue.

Comment: any ideas for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74993704/disable-logging-to-app-insights-in-azure-function?noredirect=1#comment132342471_74993704  ?