# Disable logging to App Insights in Azure Function

Tags: azure, logging, azure-functions

My logs are getting really full from a function app.

It seems as though checking for messages on a subscription and blob storage are both being logged

[image]

How can I stop this?

```
"logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "System": "Warning",
      "Host": "Error",
      "Function": "Information",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Information",
      "Azure.Storage.Blobs": "Warning",
      "Host.Functions": "Warning"
    },
    "Serilog": {
      "MinimumLevel": "Information",
      "WriteTo": [
        {
          "Name": "Console",
          "Args": {
            "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level} | {RequestId} - {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
```

Paul

Comment: Why you have set 'information' ...for Function, that imakes it too noisy.

Comment: I want logger.LogInformation calls to come up in app insights

Comment: Even if I change Function to Error I still get this happening

Answer (score 0):

You could filter out the logs getting sent to ApplicationInsights by using "ApplicationInsights" under "Logging". For example, you could update the logging configuration as

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Microsoft": "Error"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the example above, even though the default Log Level is set to "Information", for `ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider`, only Log level of **Error** and above is sent to ApplicationInsights.

See the following links for details:
[Filters for Logging with ApplicationInsights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#create-filter-rules-in-configuration-with-appsettingsjson)